# Print a very large number in unix

Tags: awk, largenumber

I have a unusual problem which I have no idea how to solve.
I have a awk script to calculate sum of different elements but at the end i have a very large number as result ( and that is normal) but my concern is how the number is displayed `1.84745e+09` .

Any idea to get the "correct" form like i mean `182739293747493274` for example

for example this is the awk code i'm using

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1 {header=$0; next} {a[$1]+=$6+$14} END {for (i in a) {print i, a[i]; tot+=a[i]} print "TOTAL", tot}' CAS01.txt CAS02.txt CAS03.txt
```

and here the output i have

```
20140201 -5.04108e+08 20140202 -5.74709e+08 20140228 -7.68633e+08 TOTAL -1.84745e+09
```

My concern is that i want the output number to be fully displayed not in exposant format

Comment: Could you use printf with %f ?

Comment: can you make a small example, so that your problem could be reproduced?

Comment: I goy this -1.84745e+09 as output! I want it to be display as -1847450000

Comment: Paraphrasing your own problem statement is hardly helpful.  Editing your question to include a code example might better help illustrate your problem.

Comment: What wrong with `awk '{printf("%i",-1.84745e+09)}`. It gives `-1847450000 `

Comment: I don't want to come back and wrote awk for each result i got. it gonna be a huge work again so i'm looking for a script which will print it directly in the format i want

Comment: @JefAime what are you talking about, how is changing a print statement to printf huge work ?

Comment: @Jidder there are hundreds of in beetwen results i got before the final one like this: "20140201" -5.04108e+08 "20140202" -5.74709e+08 "20140228" -7.68633e+08 .......... "20141002" -3.12342e+08! so writing a printf statement for each of them will be a huge result that's what i was talking about

Comment: `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf("%i ",$i);print ""}' file` ?

Answer (score 2):

GNU Awk has the extension `-M` which provides for [arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arbitrary-Precision-Integers.html).

If you can't use GNU Awk, and your Awk does not have a similar extension, you will have to switch to a tool which does (`bc` comes to mind, or try Perl; there is a tool `a2p` in the Perl distribution to translate Awk scripts to Perl code).

Answer (score 0):

You can use printf instead of print.

Example:

```
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C$ echo  12.3456 | awk '{printf ("%2.4e\n", $1)}'
1.2346e+01
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C$ echo  12.3456 | awk '{printf ("%2.4f\n", $1)}'
12.3456
```